# What's the mysql syntax to pull data on the fly

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table with a bunch of orders... one of the columns is order_status. The data in that column ranges from 1 to 5. Each number relates to a name, which is stored in another table that relates that number to the respective name.

```
SELECT order_id , order_status FROM tablename1
```

The above would just return the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 for order status. How can i query within the query on the fly to replace these numbers with their respective names.

Also, what's the term used to describe this. I'd Google it if i knew what the appropriate term was.

Comment: Are you looking to be able to set the order status via query?

Comment: You need a `JOIN` to the other table which contains the names of the order statuses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each number relates to a name, which is stored in another table that
>   relates that number to the respective name.

[**`JOIN`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) it with the other table:

```
SELECT 
  t.order_id, 
  s.StatusName
FROM tablename1 AS t
INNER JOIN the statusesTable AS s ON t.order_status = s.status_id;
```